# How to make GitHub action trigger on push.paths AND push.tags?

Tags: github-actions

I have tried the following:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'document.tex'
    tags:
      - '**'
```

The action is triggered when creating a tag. But when I make some changes to `document.tex` and push, it is not triggered.

How to make it being triggered by both events?

Comment: Is `document.tex` located on the root of your repo?

Comment: @Azeem yes, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, specifying `tags:` explicitly only adds a *filter* for which tags will trigger the workflow, but omitting `tags:` makes the workflow trigger on any tag.

So the solution is as simple as:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'document.tex'
```

This workflow triggers on both, pushes to the specified paths, and tags.